# MvvmCross MvxListView ItemClick Enabled Based on property

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

So I have a MvxListView

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:id="@+id/receptionsListView"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_supplier"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ReceptionSuppliersList;  ItemClick SelectReceptionCommand;" />
```

I want to enabled/disabled some Items based on a value from model in the list. Something like

```
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ReceptionSuppliersList; ItemClick SelectReceptionCommand; Enabled ReceptionSuppliersList.IsValid" />
```

From what I've tested this just disabled all my list items because there is no such property ReceptionSuppliersList.IsValid ( it's ReceptionSuppliersList[i].IsValid ). How can I achive this.

I also tried to add the Enabled Property on item_supplier like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    style="@style/ExtendProTheme.ReceptionItem"
    local:MvxBind="Enabled IsValid" >
```

But it still doesn't work.

Any ideas how can i disable some of the item from my list based on a property?

PS :
My items look like this

```
public string Username { get; set; }

public string DeviceId { get; set; }

public bool IsValid { get; set; }
```

Comment: do you have something in your Output? Some bindings errors maybe?

Comment: I don't see any error on my binding.

Comment: Have you tried binding `Enabled` on the root of item template instead of the `MvxListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom adapter to handle the enabling/disabling of list items. You would just need to cast the Adapters `ItemsSource` to your ViewModels
ReceptionSuppliersList type in the `IsEnabled` override.

```
public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) 
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) 
        : base(context, bindingContext)
    {
    }

    protected CustomAdapter(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) :
        base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsEnabled(int position)
    {
        var items = ItemsSource as List<TestModel>;
        return items[position].IsValid;
    }
}
```

Assign adapter to your MvxListView:

```
var receptionsListView = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.receptionsListView);
receptionsListView.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, BindingContext as IMvxAndroidBindingContext);
```

Comment: @CiucaS, did this give you what you were looking for?

Comment: the requests had changed and it should be enable with a error message on click so I did not implemented it yet. Anyhow I would like to do it in case i need it in the future just to test it, but i've been busy. I'll try to get to it as soon as i find some free time. I did not forget.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a real problem-solve, but it should work for your case:

1. Add gray overlay on the item to make it look like it's not enabled.
2. Check whether item is enabled on the method handler for SelectReceptionCommand.

```
    
    private void OnSelectReceptionCommandExecuted(Reception item)
            {
                if (!reception.IsEnabled)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // your code here
            }
```

Comment: I thought of this as a solution, but I would really like a more elegant one. This is just a nasty workaround which shouldn't be the case.